# Lock custom task pane context menu in Outlook VSTO Add-in

Tags: .net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

Is there any way to lock the context menu offered by the custom task pane?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Outlook extensibility model doesn't provide anything for that out of the box. As a possible workaround you may consider creating an Outlook form region. See [Create Outlook form regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/creating-outlook-form-regions?view=vs-2022) for more information.

Also you may consider using [Advanced Outlook view and form regions](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/outlook-regions-basics.php).

Comment: Out of curiosity, you talk often about Outlook extensibility model, what do you refer by Outlook extensibility model? May I assume that it is not the standard Outlook API?

Comment: By saying extensibility model I mean first of all the Outlook object model, Fluent UI, COM extensions and web add-ins API, task panes and Outlook form regions and etc. Everything that allows to extend built-in features.

Comment: Do you know some third party tools that you would recommend to create Outlook Add-ins? Third party to extend Outlook features or make things easier so we can focus on coding and be more productive. For example I have found Add-in Express: https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/index.php Would you recommend using third-parties or better to not use them?

Comment: I've spent seven years in the office working for Add-in Express. So, I definitely can recommend their tools for saving your time. But VSTO is a good choice as well.